# How to replace hard coded value with dynamic input variable in the outputs - Github actions

Tags: github, replace, syntax, github-actions, key-value

Harded code value `app_name` was here and it worked fine ->       `app_namexx: ${{ steps.run-script.outputs.app_name }}`

I now wish to replace hard coded `app_name` to input variable `key_name`. So, Tried the below but I get error:

```
name: CALLER main yml

on:
  push:
    branches: main
  workflow_dispatch:  
    
    inputs:
      key_name:
        required: true
        default: 'app_name'
   
jobs:
  mainjob1:
    runs-on: "windows-latest"
    
    outputs:
      app_namexx: ${{ steps.run-script.outputs.[key_name] }}  

    steps:        
      - name: Checkout  repository
        uses: actions/checkout@v3
```

Error output:

```
The workflow is not valid. Error from called workflow. Unrecognized named-value: 'key_name'. Located at position 27 with expression: steps.run-script.outputs[key_name]
```

I tried the following but none of it works:

```
app_namexx: ${{ steps.run-script.outputs[key_name] }}
app_namexx: ${{ steps.run-script.outputs[$key_name] }}
app_namexx: ${{ steps.run-script.outputs.$key_name }}
app_namexx: ${{ steps.run-script.outputs.${key_name} }}
app_namexx: ${{ steps.run-script.outputs.${ inputs.key_name } }}
```

The purpose of variabelizing `outputs` is every time a new `key_name` is passed the reusable workflow will return a different value for that `key_name` by parsing an key-value style XML using PowerShell. Below are a few sample snapshots of different `key-name` to powershell script and the output returned. If `key_name` is blank then it will return all key-value pairs:

[image]

Thus, based upon the `inputs.key_name` passed by the user or if kept empty the caller workflow should get the value returned by the reusable workflow.

I may have to share a new post when dealing with return value for all key-values returned in case `-key_name` is empty ""

Comment: You would also need to update the output name when setting it using `echo "${{inputs.key_name}}" >> $env:GITHUB_OUTPUT`. Is there a reason why the step output name has to be dynamic? Because the `mainjob1` output name will still be `app_namexx` anyway, so I wonder what you will gain by making this change.

Comment: @GuiFalourd i could not understand the solution you are proposing as you have not touched upon `outputs:
      app_namexx: ${{ steps.run-script.outputs.[key_name] }}`  The dynamic `key_name` helps fetch dynamic values from a (XML)file so `app_namexx` will get different values for different `key_name` passed to this reusable workflow.

Comment: I wasn't suggesting an answer yet :) Just getting more context and informing the dynamic input value should be used somewhere else in the workflow as well here to set the output. I'll make some tests here now that I get what you want to achieve.

Comment: @GuiFalourd i have updated the original post with a brief explanation of the need and what I m trying to achieve.

Comment: It seems the following syntax is accepted by the Github interpreter: `app_namexx: ${{ steps.run-script.outputs.inputs.key_name}}` however it doesn't seem to be setting the output variable as expected (it also works with `app_namexx: ${{ steps.run-script.outputs.env.key_name}}` if using env variables at the workflow level). I'm making some tests [here](https://github.com/GuillaumeFalourd/poc-github-actions/actions/workflows/workflow-tester81.yml) using this [workflow config](https://github.com/GuillaumeFalourd/poc-github-actions/blob/main/.github/workflows/workflow-tester81.yml).

Comment: @GuiFalourd this is a reusable template so it ought to be `inputs` and not `env.key_name` please correct me if that is not the case.

Comment: You can set the inputs as env variable in any workflow to use them in steps operations. What you can't do is shared the whole env context from the main workflow to a reusable one.

Comment: @GuiFalourd please let me know where you tested this so I can have a look / leverage -> `You can set the inputs as env variable`

Comment: It was in this commit: https://github.com/GuillaumeFalourd/poc-github-actions/blob/69e313c0e69e19dc76041c11e1bdbd55d6869c9d/.github/workflows/workflow-tester81.yml